# Is it possible to have iOS simulator in my Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, ios

> iOS Simulator for Linux Mint OS

I need to have `iOS simulator` for my `Linux Mint OS` to check my website responsive in various iOS devices is this possible as I know this feature is available in almost all MAC systems but I cannot afford MAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to test it would be through a browser extension that automatically resizes the browser to resolutions specific to mobile devices. There's even extensions that will request mobile sites.

The not so quick way, is to use an online simulator like http://transmog.net/ or https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live#ios

Comment: Bro thankyou anyway those links helped they gave me exact o/p what it really gets in actual devices :)

Comment: In the case of iPhone, resizing is far from enough.
Also, chrome & firefox has a built in "device mode", where you can choose or define screen size.  no extension is required.

Comment: The guy asks for a simulator and you offer him to adapt screen sizes as if running an iOS app was only about the size... pretty poor. You need to bear in mind all other aspects that imply running something on that other platform. By the way, one of the links your provided doesn't even work.

Comment: @Noctumsempra the question was about running a web app under iOS, not a native iOS app. Given how restrictive iOS is, and the fact that the only way to run a proper emulator is on macOS, that’s the best answer I could come up with. Feel free to make another suggestion if you have anything better in mind.

Comment: Oh, and transmog.net was working at the time I wrote the answer. Things change on the web, especially since May 2015.

Answer (score 20):

Two solutions:

- **OSX Virtual Machine**: Run a *VMWare OSX image* inside Linux and install *XCode*. You will have the most accurate iOS emulator where you can choose iPad2, iPad. iPhone5, iPhone6, 6+, rotation of screen, etc.
- **Google Chrome**: Load your webpage, right click and click on *Inspect Element*. On the new window called *Developer Tools* click on the mobile phone icon and now you get a very good emulator of iOS / Android and Windows Phone devices (Mobile and tablet).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but the above answer solved my need anyway :)

Comment: I think this is the better answer. :D

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that running a macOS VM on a non-Apple hardware host system is against Apple EULA and ToS. Also keep in mind that performance on an x86_64 VM running an emulator of an arm64 platform like iOS or iPadOS is going to be pretty bad, even if you have a monster of a system. Having said that, it may be sufficient for basic web app layout rendering tests, but if your app does anything computationally intensive, this testing platform may not useful.